# Julia Gtk Windows do not display outside REPL

Tags: linux, gtk, julia, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to use Julia with the Gtk package outside the REPL.

Using this code:

```
Using Gtk.ShortNames
win = @Window("My Window")
```

in the REPL works, but the same code put in a test.jl file and using:

```
julia test.jl
```

in the command line does not work.

I have tried the method written here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/Gtk.jl

```
Using Gtk.ShortNames

win = @Window("gtkwait")

# Put your GUI code here

if !isinteractive()
    c = Condition()
    signal_connect(win, :destroy) do widget
        notify(c)
    end
    wait(c)
end
```

The code runs but no window appears.

If it's any help, I'm on Manjaro Linux with 4.1 Linux Kernel and have both GTK2 and GTK3 librairies installed.

Comment: You may need to call `showall()` (which I *think* is the equivalent to `gtk_widge_show_all()`) on the window to show it. This is what happens with normal GTK+.

Comment: I've tried using this function but it still does not work outside REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code, which is literally what the documentation says to do, doesn't work for me either (Julia 0.4.0, Gtk.jl 0.9.2). Maybe the documentation is outdated.

What works is to use `Gtk.gtk_main` and `Gtk.gtk_quit`:

```
using Gtk.ShortNames
win = @Window("Hello")
signal_connect(win, :destroy) do widget
    Gtk.gtk_quit()
end
Gtk.gtk_main()
```

I don't know if this is the "right" way, but it does work and is closer to how things work in GTK+'s C API (with `gtk_main` and `gtk_main_quit`).